# Find the Dimension of the Centraliser of Matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Let \begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix}8 & -9 & -2 \\ 6 & -7 & -2 \\ -6 & 9 & 4 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Let \begin{equation}
V(A) = \{X \in M_{3}(R) : AX = XA \}
\end{equation}

where $M_{3}(R)$ is the vector space of $3 \times 3$ real matrices.

Calculate the dimension of $V(A)$.

So far, I have found that A has eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ with corresponding eigenvector $\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and $\lambda = 2$ with corresponding eigenvectors $\vec{v_{1}} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{2} \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{v_{2}} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

I do not know what to do about this centraliser though. All I can tell is that obviously $I,A,A^{-1}$ will all commute with A, so that would bring the dimension up to at least 2? And I understand that the maximumm is 9, but that's about it.

Must you always compute the basis for such a set to find its dimension? Or is there a simple way to predict what the dimension of $V(A)$ will be without doing so? Thanks.

Comment: compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884923/find-all-matrices-which-commutes-with-a from a few hours ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Usually to find the centraliser of a matrix $A$ you have to diagonalise the matrix (if it's possible) and write $A = PDP^{-1}$. Since :

$$ X \mapsto P^{-1}XP $$

is a bijection it then suffices to describe the set :

$$ \{ Y \in \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R) | DY = YD \} $$

with $D$ the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, A is in this case not diagonalisable. (Determinant of P is 0) What do we do in this case?
Thank you very much for this answer, though!

Comment: Well then the matrix is triangularisable ! After finding the matrix $T$ such that $A = PTP^{-1}$ the system will become $TY = YT$ and can be easily solved !